# Best way to update Spartan Config

Tags: mesosphere, dcos

I've installed DC/OS to a new cluster and am learning it. Bootstrapping and installing was a relatively okay process; I chose the advanced method and found it to be the easiest to get working with our system.

Once deployed, I'm confused about how I am to go about updating the cluster configuration (the values I'd provided with bootstrap). Does DC/OS do anything to help here, or is configuration relatively static?

Specifically, I'd like to modify the configuration of Spartan to:

- Only listen on the dummy device (it's listening on all of them at the moment)
- Configure a zone specific resolver (I was told it's possible https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns/pull/441)

Comment: I've discovered via my own research that the version of Spartan deployed by DC/OS 1.7 (current version as of today) is a bit behind the code in GitHub. While the version in GitHub provides the Spartan option I want in order to change :53 listening device(s), the option does not exist in the version deployed by DC/OS 1.7; further, the upstream zone-specific resolvers in latest Spartan are hard-coded and not configurable. Additionally, pkgpanda, the DC/OS home-brewed package management system, does not appear to support individual packages (I was told so in the DC/OS slack room).

Answer (score 0):

According to [DCOS docs](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.9/administration/installing/custom/configuration-parameters/) for 1.9 (see "resolvers" option), upstream DNS servers cannot be changed once provided during bootstrap.

> "Upstream DNS Servers [...] Caution: If you set this parameter
>   incorrectly you will have to reinstall DC/OS."